# both keywordp and macrop then eval from a functionp

Tags: elisp, elisp-macros, common-lisp, eval-expression

'Hope it won't bother my using `defmacro`s named in *the style of **keywords*** (colon-prefixed, e.g., `:set-this` or `:get-that`): it apparently tricks `ELisp` from otherwise requiring ***`quote`d*** symbols (`'`) or *function* symbols (`#'`).

For example:

```
(foo :set-this value-that) ; line 0
```

Nevermind that: the problem goes as follows.

Say there are two "`keywordp`"-like `defmacro`s with one parameter, and given a `cl-flet*` context, there should be ***two** similar* forms (as in `line #0`), but with two different macros and arguments.

An **MWE** is the following.

```
(defmacro :m (x) `(length ,x)) ; line 1
    ⇒ :m
(and (keywordp :m) (macrop :m)) ; line 2
    ⇒ t

(:m `(3)) ; line 3
    ⇒ 1

(defmacro :w (x) `(length (nreverse ,x))) ; line 4
    ⇒ :w
(and (keywordp :w) (macrop :w)) ; line 5
    ⇒ t

(:w `(6)) ; line 6
    ⇒ 1

(defun x (y z) (eval `(,y ,z))) ; line 7
    ⇒ x

(x :m `(8)) ; line 8
    ⇒ Invalid function: 8

(x :w '(9)) ; line 9
    ⇒ Invalid function: 8

(- (eval `(:m '(8)) (eval `(:w `(9))) ; line 10
    ⇒ 0
```

The **faulty code** is in **line `#7`**.

In these simple cases, it don't matter if the argument-list is backquoted ``(8)`, quoted `'(9)`, or returned as `(list 8)`.

Lines `#8` and `#9` show what is wrong.

Yet, line `#10` shows that `eval`uating as it "*should be*" is possible.

Now, if instead of `defun` there were a `defmacro`:

```
(defmacro x (y z) `(eval (,y ,z))) ; line 11
    ⇒ x
```

then lines `#8` or `#9` would be equivalent to line `10`, but this is impossible within a `cl-flet*`.

Any hints? Thank s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for line 7:

```
(defun x (y z) (eval `(,y ',z)))
```

That is, ensure that the second argument is quoted in the expansion.  When you call `` (x :m `(8)) ``, in your version the body of `x` ends up as:

```
(eval '(:m (8)))
```

which obviously implies a call to the function `8`.  With the extra quote in the definition of `x`, it would try this instead:

```
(eval '(:m '(8)))
```

which passes the list `(8)` to the `:m` macro without evaluating it.

Comment: Yes, this is it, or double quote ''(8) because `defun` removes one quote.